# How to Awk Paragraph in complex text file?

Tags: linux, awk, paragraph

I have a simple log file which is very messy and I need it to be neat. The file contains log headers but are all jumbled up together therefore I need to sort the log files according to the log headers. There are no static number of lines that means that there is no fix number of lines for the each header of the text file. And I am using AWK to sort out the headers.

The Log files goes something like this:

```
Car LogFile Header
<text>
<text>
<text>
Car LogFile Header
<text>
Car LogFile Header
<and so forth>
```

It would be outputted like this:

```
Car LogFile Header
<text>
<text>
<text>
-------------------
Car Logfile Header
<text>
<text>
```

I have done up/searched a simple code but it does not seem to be working. Can someone please guide me? Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

# usage: pargrep <infile> <searchpattern>

inFile="$1"
searchString="$2"

awk '
BEGIN {
    FS="\n"
    RS="-----"
}
/'"$searchString"'/ { print }
' ${inFile}
```

Comment: "it does not seem to be working" isn't very informative. How does its behavior differ from what you expect and what error messages are you getting?

Comment: It gives an error of "awk: cmd. line:6: //root/Desktop/Default.log/ { print }
awk: cmd. line:6:                       ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:6: //root/Desktop/Default.log/ { print }
awk: cmd. line:6:                            ^ unterminated regexp"

Comment: it would be good if you could us sample input and expected output. Thanks

Comment: I can't directly place any results here cause of policy reasons but if you look at my post I need the result for the text file to be something as shown in the above [EDITED]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use variable passing instead of trying to get complex quoting right.

```
#!/bin/bash

# usage: pargrep <infile> <searchpattern>

inFile="$1"
searchString="$2"

awk -v selector=$searchString '
    BEGIN {
        FS="\n"
        RS="-----"
    }
    selector ~ $0 { print }
    ' "${inFile}"
```

Comment: Now it gives me the error of "awk: cmd. line:3: fatal: cannot open file `pargrep' for reading (No such file or directory)" ..... Any thoughts in that? Is that problem due to the extra usage calling?

Comment: @JavaNoob: Same error message? What version of awk? What distribution of Linux?

Comment: AWK version 3.1.5 and Red Hat 5.

Comment: @JavaNoob: Then you shouldn't be getting that error message. Double check that you're not missing any single quotes `'` or double quotes `"` or have any extra of either.

Answer (score 2):

Tweaking Dennis' answer a bit:

```
awk -v selector="$searchString" '
    BEGIN { 
        RS = "Car LogFile Header\n" 
        ORS = "------"
    }
    selector ~ $0 { 
        print RS $0 
    }
' "${inFile}"
```

Note that `RS` is the **input** record separator.  I used `ORS` to illustrate.

I assume that "Car LogFile Header" is constant.  If that is dynamic, let us know.